# Unknown X-Men: Something to do with Motorcycles

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification

I remember reading this comic in the very early days of the New Mutants, likely the first year of their series and somewhere most likely in the 1-10 in the series.  This mutant wasn't a X-man, I don't think, and too old to be a New Mutant.

The story this guy was in was basically an addendum or a bonus feature at the back of a New Mutant comic tracking a separate group.  I seem to remember that he had some exposure to Prof X, but wasn't an X-man per se.  Like the New Mutants, he was definitely learning to come into his powers.  But he seemed older.  Also wasn't confirmed yet if he was going to be a good guy or not.

Anyway his ability seemed concentrated around the motorcycle, like he could make it do things, and he was jumping all over the place from his bike to the villains.  Riding ability was definitely part of it.  And he had traditional biker gear on.  That's all I really can remember.  Anyone know who this is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderiders?

Comment: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/black-marauder/4005-31232/

Comment: @Valorum It was the Marauder, or Wolf

Comment: @Valorum  Or in this case the Dark Rider

Comment: It was episode 6 of the New Mutants: http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix5/marauder_teamam.htm

Comment: Awesome. Now self-answer it and get ready for an upvote!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Valorum indicated the individual is The Dark Rider, [aka Marauder and Masked Marauder](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/black-marauder/4005-31232/) a gestalt being that was formed from a band of mutants called Team America.  (They have somehow lost the copyright to that name, or didn't have it.)

The character I was thinking of was Wolf, a member of that team, who channeled The Dark Rider in [episode 6 of The New Mutants](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix5/marauder_teamam.htm).